# 503 Service Unavailable error in linkedin api

Tags: linkedin-api

We have used https://api.linkedin.com/v2/industries api to get industries details but this api getting failed and returns status code as 503

```
note : random linkedin api returns status code as 503. 

like - 
  https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations
  https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityFollowerStatistics
  https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationPageStatistics
```

I have used Access Token, and this error occurred last 24 Hrs only.

Comment: Are you passing the api key, oauth token and the payload as expected? You need to post some code snippet in order to get proper help.

Comment: I have used Accesstoken

Comment: Can you post your request / code snippet?